# state is not updating in child component after updated inside parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Parent component updating its Boolean state and sending this state to child but in child this updated state is not reflecting.

```
 const [showSeeAllNewsComponent, setShowSeeAllNews] = useState(false);
 const onClickSeeAll_news = isShown => {
    console.log("back", isShown, !isShown);
    setShowSeeAllNews(isShown);
  };
 const onBottomEventSeeAlluser = async () => {
    if (showSeeAllNewsComponent) {
        Pagination.offset = Pagination.offset + 1;
        await HomeAPI.newsDetail(Pagination.offset, Pagination.limit).then(
            userData=> {
                console.log(userData.data, loading);
                setUserData(userPData=>([...userPData, ...userData.data]));      
            }
        );
    }
  };
return(
 <Header  onBackClick={(valBool: boolean) => onClickSeeAll_news(valBool)} isheaderBreadCrumb={showSeeAllNewsComponent}></Header>
{showSeeAllUserComponent ? <AllUser userDataNews={userData}  onBottomEvent={onBottomEventSeeAllUser}  isShown={showSeeAllUserComponent} ></AllUser> : <div>Some Other Component</div>
)
```

showSeeAllUserComponent is not working in AllUser child component.but in Header child component its working.Is that because of scroll event. in child component.Even The All User Component Is not shown onBottomEvent is triggered when we reach the bottom of thre page

child component

```
function AllUser({ userDataNews, onBottomEvent,isShown }) {
  useEffect(() => {

    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScrollCheck, true);
  }, []);
  const onScrollCheck = event => { 
    if(isShown){
       event.target.scrollHeight - event.target.scrollTop ===
       event.target.clientHeight
        ? onBottomEvent()
        : "";
    }
  };
}
```

**EdiT**
scrollcheck repeatedly called and also it calls api if child component not shown

```
const [showSeeAllNewsComponent, setShowSeeAllNews] = useState(false);

 const onScrollCheck = event => {
    console.log("scrollchecks", showSeeAllNewsComponent);
     if (showSeeAllNewsComponent) {
    event.target.scrollHeight - event.target.scrollTop ===
    event.target.clientHeight
      ? onBottomEventSeeAllNews()
      : "";
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScrollCheck, true);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScrollCheck);
  }, [onScrollCheck]);

 const onClickSeeAll_news = isShown => {
    console.log("back", isShown, !isShown);
    setShowSeeAllNews(isShown);
  };
 const onBottomEventSeeAlluser = async () => {
    if (showSeeAllNewsComponent) {
        Pagination.offset = Pagination.offset + 1;
        await HomeAPI.newsDetail(Pagination.offset, Pagination.limit).then(
            userData=> {
                console.log(userData.data, loading);
                setUserData(userPData=>([...userPData, ...userData.data]));      
            }
        );
    }
  };
 return(
 <Header  onBackClick={(valBool: boolean) => onClickSeeAll_news(valBool)} 
 isheaderBreadCrumb={showSeeAllNewsComponent}></Header>
 {showSeeAllUserComponent ? <AllUser userDataNews={userData}    isShown= 
 {showSeeAllUserComponent} ></AllUser> : <div>Some Other Component</div>
 )
```

Comment: your AllUser component doesn't render anything?

Comment: Didn't added render part here

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `onScrollCheck` to the useEffect dependencies, otherwise your use effect will not be called when isShown changes:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScrollCheck, true);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScrollCheck);
  }, [onScrollCheck]);
```

If you're afraid of performance issues you can use [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) for onScrollCheck:

```
  const onScrollCheck = useCallback(event => { 
    if(isShown){
       event.target.scrollHeight - event.target.scrollTop ===
       event.target.clientHeight
        ? onBottomEvent()
        : "";
    }
  }, [isShown, onBottomEvent]);
```

Comment: Even If the child component AllUSer is not shown onBottomEvent is triggered .and also I added if(showSeeAllNewsComponent) condition for checking whether AllUser component is shown or not.If shown make an api call inside onBottomEventSeeAlluser .But bypasses condition makes an api call if compoenent not shown and showSeeAllNewsComponent is false

Comment: you want to fire onBottomEvent even if AllUser is not shown? can you rephrase please, I didn't really get that

Comment: In alluser i'm listening for user scroll to bottom of the page.When bottom of the page is reached I trigger Onbottom event  from AllUser.So parent component Can call api inside nBottomEventSeeAlluser.

Comment: if you are not using anything inside AllUser (you add a scroll event to window) then you should move this event listener to the parent.

Comment: I'm rendering data inside AllUser

Comment: I know, but you should move the event listener to the parent if it doesn't depend on the child component

Comment: ok I added thes listener inside parent.and Once User reaches bottom I check whether AllUSer Component shown inside onScrollCheck if(showSeeAllNewsComponent) but the condition is true it makes api call even the AllUserComponent not shown .I don't know where I'm going wrong

Comment: you still need to add onScrollCheck to your dependencies array of useEffect like in my response

Comment: onScrollCheck repeatedly called and alson Even the if condition returns true and calls api